# Can asymptotic of a Mellin (or laplace inverse ) be evaluated?

Tags: integral-transforms

I mean, given the Mellin inverse integral $ \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}dsF(s)x^{-s} $, can we evaluate this integral, at least as $ x \rightarrow \infty $?

Can the same be made for $ \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}dsF(s)\exp(st) $ as $ x \rightarrow \infty $?

Why or why not can this be evaluated in order to get the asymptotic behaviour of Mellin inverse transforms?

Answer (score 1):

yes we can evaluate above integral but it depends on F(s).what is your F(s).then we can see how to solve it.above integral is inverse mellin transform.Some times it is v difficult to find inverse,it all depends on what F(s) is.

Comment: $F(s)= \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ , the problem here is the infinite number of poles of $ F(s) $

Comment: @JoseGarcia I seriously doubt your going to find a simple asymptotic expression for the mertens function.